# inserting a COUNT value into an another specific row from another table

Tags: mysql

MySQL beginner here.

Im working on this MySQL project and i cant figure this out.

I have two tables, the 'employee' one and the 'company' one.

Each employee works for one company. I want to insert a new column into the company table called 'NumberOfEmployees'.

I have tried using a COUNT method but i cant figure out how to insert the count result into the correct row (in this case the row where the BrandName is ASUS).

This is what i have been doing.

```
CREATE TABLE company (
    BrandName varchar(255) DEFAULT '' not null,
    EstabYear int,
    Adress varchar(255),
    Email varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (BrandName),
    FOREIGN KEY (Email) REFERENCES manager(Email)
);

CREATE TABLE ergazomenos (
    FirstName varchar(255),
    LastName varchar(255),
    WorkExp int,
    DateOfHire varchar(10),
    BrandName varchar(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (BrandName) REFERENCES Company(BrandName)
);

ALTER TABLE company ADD NoOfEmp int;

INSERT INTO etaireia (NoOfEmp)
VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(BrandName)
        FROM employee
        WHERE BrandName = 'ASUS'));
```

Comment: **NO!!!** Dont do it! There is so much scope for mistakes in doing that. If you want to know that number just run a `count()` query

Comment: Why don't any of these tables have a `PRIMARY KEY`? For your own sake, do not use arbitrary names as foreign keys. A good foreign key is something that is issued once, never changed, and more importantly, *never* recycled. For example, an `AUTO_INCREMENT INT`.